# Why is my imported variable undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is my Angular app, and I wanted to move my HTML template to separeted file (template.ts):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Template} from './template'

export class entity {
    id:number;
    name:string;
    dob:string;
}

let USERS: entity[] = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Jon Smith', dob: '01.10.1990'},
    {id: 1, name: 'asd qwe', dob: '22.04.1988'}
];

let myTemplate: Template;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: myTemplate.code,
})

export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Angular';
    Users = USERS;
}
```

Template file:

```
export class Template {
    code:string =`
            <h1>Список</h1>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> id </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th> {{Users[0].id}} </th>
                        <th> {{Users[0].name}} </th>
                        <th> {{Users[0].dob}} </th>
                        <th> <button class="crud__DeleteEditButton form-control" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#myModal"> </button> </th>
                        <th> <button class="crud__DeleteEditButton form-control"> </button> </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th> {{Users[1].id}} </th>
                        <th> {{Users[1].name}} </th>
                        <th> {{Users[1].dob}} </th>
                        <th> <button class="crud__DeleteEditButton form-control"> </button> </th>
                        <th> <button class="crud__DeleteEditButton form-control"> </button> </th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    `
}
```

But I keep getting 'Cannot read property of undefined' error on `template = myTemplate.code`
What is wrong?
Here is my AppModule file:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import {Template} from "./template";

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, Template ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [Template]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I would recommend having template in separate HTML file and set templateurl to that file.

Comment: Your `export class AppComponent` is really weird. Don't abuse classes! I suspect you were looking for `export const AppComponent =`

Comment: Just FYI, `Entity` should be an `interface`, you are creating a subtle trap for yourself and future maintainers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

better use the property `templateUrl` and provide a path to the html template in a html file.

Further reading: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#components

---

You are getting the error, because you say the variable is the type of Template, but the variable never gets something assigned.

Also you could do this:

```
export class Template {
    public static readonly code: string =`<h1>Список</h1>`
}
```

And

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: Template.code,
})
// ...
```

But beware, I would strongly recommend using a HTML file as template, like mentioned above.

Comment: Now _this_ is abuse of classes. Why in the world would you wrap a simple constant into a static (mutable) property of a function object that never gets called?

Comment: I would not at all, like I wrote. But still better than calling new and instantiating new objects, just to access an static string.

Comment: While you are correct that using a template file is a better approach, if you are going to use a `ts`/`js` file just use modules. This is JavaScript, damn it. Just export the value and don't create wasteful, error-opportune abstractions that are not even used. Just learn the language. `export const x = 1;` `import {x} from './x';`. Why are you using a class?

Comment: Just didn't want to alter his code that much for the example to understand. Since his question was, why his code is not working and not how to import the template. And if we are going to export a variable, I wouldn't do that way at all and using a HTML template in the first place.

Comment: You made the variable a `static` mutable property of a function that is defined for no reason. This goes against TypeScript and JavaScript programming guidelines. It is also pointless. Learn how JavaScript works.

Answer (score -1):

You are exporting a class that when instantiated will have property `code` of type `string` containing your template.

Angular expects the template to be a string, not a class. To resolve this, just export the string itself

```
export const template = `<h1>Список</h1>`;
```

Furthermore, a provider is a class or function that creates a service. `template` is not a service and it must not be provided.

Finally, your component will look as follows

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {template} from './template';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: template
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  Users = USERS;
}
```